# PhpStorm remote host panel does not show the latest files on remote server

Tags: phpstorm

I have added the last two days serveral files  with phpstorm to a website on a remote host. Yestereday the remote host panel still showed them, but today they are not visible in the remote host panel anymore. However, these 'missing' files are still on the remote server, because I can see them in the website online.

Comment: Too broad... Maybe you are checking wrong server and especially folder? have you tried "Refresh" button? I mean - without knowing all your details ... so far it sounds like some user error.

Comment: I have tried the refresh button and checked exactly the same server/folder as the day before with the same connection, when it still did show everything.

Comment: Maybe file permission then (that prevent even from viewing them)? Otherwise I do not see many ideas. What kind of names they have? Maybe they fall under "excluded" somehow (but it still shows me such files here .. and they excluded from transfer and not from showing up). Enable detailed logging and check the log - see what RAW FTP transfer will tell (if those files will be listed or not). https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs

Comment: I am trying to set up the website with laravel. The files that are missing have .php extensions. For instance the whole resources map with all views ( blade.php files) is now empty. debugging gave the follwing information for the recourse mapdrwxrwxr-x   6 bitnami daemon    4096 Aug  8 14:33 resources
:  into this folder I even uploaded with phpstorm a few new blade.php view files.

Comment: I mean the remote host panel show the resources folder is empty. On the remote host this folder isn't empty.

Comment: What the extra log says? Maybe it's a matter of settings Passive Mode for FTP or some another option in Connection Settings? You have little to no details .. so nothing concrete can be said here, unless someone have faced exactly the same situation.

Comment: Problem solved. It turned out that they were working on the internet calbles in our neighbourhood and the internet connection was soo slow and disturbed that phpstorm couldn't build up a normal connection with the remote server. Now everything is normal again. Thanks for all your help